# Update column value when row is not numeric

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I am running a process that checks to see if a row value is numeric. If it is not numeric, a column called 'Flag' is updated with the keyword 'Error'

I can do this in SQL using the ISNUMERIC function. I attempted to do this with pandasql's sqldf function but received the error message `no such function: ISNUMERIC`
This is a sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'P1':  [0, 'ABC', 1.1]
        }
originaldf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is my desired output

```
P1 | Flag
---|------
0  | 
ABC| Error
1.1|
```

This is what is throwing the no such function: ISNUMERIC error

```
import pandasql as ps
newdf= ps.sqldf('''
             SELECT *,
                 CASE
                     WHEN
                         ISNUMERIC(P1) < 0 THEN 'ERROR'
                 END
                    AS `Flag`
             FROM originaldf
                            ''')
```

After researching this I decided to move on from trying to use the ISNUMERIC function in this ps.sqldf query and use this instead. However, while this did not throw an error, it did not work either.

```
import pandasql as ps
newdf= ps.sqldf('''
             SELECT *,
                 CASE
                     WHEN
                         P1 LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%' THEN 'ERROR'
                 END
                    AS `Flag`
             FROM originaldf
                            ''')
#newdf
P1 | Flag
---|------
0  | 
ABC|
1.1|
```

After this, I also tried using df.iterrows()
I did this by doing this:

```
    for idx, row in originaldf.iterrows():
        if str(row['P1']) == '%[A-Za-z]%':
            row['Flag'] = 'Error'
```

This did not return an error but sadly did not work as well. I suspect that it is because I am not using this '%[A-Za-z]%' correctly.

Any tips to get going in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Idk about what you are doing wrong, but you can use `'%[\D|^.]*'%` instead of `'%[A-Za-z]%'`

Comment: cool, ill try it ^

Comment: Also, idk if you already did this, but you can test your regex against a non-numeric string in Python first

Comment: Why not just stick to pandas/numpy? must you use `sql`?

Comment: totally could ^ other than using df.iterrows(),  i'm not sure how to accomplish what I'd like to do otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `is_numeric()` function and apply it to the `P1` column like below.

```
data = {'P1':  [0, 'ABC', 1.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def is_numeric(x):
    result = 'error'
    if type(x) in (int, float):
        result = ''
    return result

df['Flag'] = df['P1'].apply(is_numeric)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an alphabetical check as:

```
originaldf['Flag'] = originaldf.P1.astype(str).apply(str.isalpha).map({True: "Error"})
originaldf
```

Which will give you:

|  | P1 | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | nan |
| 1 | ABC | Error |
| 2 | 1.1 | nan |